# Why do Amazon S3 returns me an Error 330 about simple files?

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I have added the "Content-Encoding: gzip" header to my S3 files and now when I try to access them, it returns me a "Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED)".

Note that my files are simply images, js and css.

How do I solve that issue?

Comment: This usually happens when you uncompressed files (i.e. the non-gzipped versions) have the `Content-Encoding: gzip` applied on them. The encoding header's only for gzipped files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're going to have to manually gzip them and then upload them to S3.  S3 doesn't have the ability to gzip on the fly like your web server does.

EDIT:  Images are already compressed so don't gzip them.

Comment: _"Image and PDF files should not be gzipped because they are already compressed."_ Relevant link: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you are using Grunt as deployment tool but, use this to compress your files:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress

Then:

https://github.com/MathieuLoutre/grunt-aws-s3

To upload compressed files to Amazon S3. Et voila!